# CMAKE should add_dependencies be transitive on target_link_libraries?

Tags: cmake

I'm specifically building for VS but wondering if this is expected to work in cmake.

Say I build some exe with a cmake list file:

```
add_executable(my_tool something.c)
```

Then I have a library that uses my_tool as an external tool without linking to it (it starts that tool as a separate process so that tool must be built):

```
add_library(my_helper helper.c)
add_dependencies(my_helper my_tool)
```

Finally, I have a bunch of other executables that use the helper, and look like this:

```
add_executable(my_test test.c)
target_link_libraries(my_test my_helper)
```

Now, when I generate this as a VS solution, and just try to build the project for "my_test" I expect that it will depend on the library "my_helper", because it must link to it, and then VS will build "my_tool" because "my_helper" should be dependent on it.

However, what I find is that "my_tool" does not get built automatically like this.

If instead, I add another dependency to the top level exe, then it works as expected:

```
add_executable(my_test test.c)
target_link_libraries(my_test my_helper)
add_dependencies(my_test my_tool)
```

I'd rather not add this to every target like "my_test" because there are many of those and it's something that can easily be missed when linking to "my_helper". But is this the only way to do it?

Comment: Probably not the issue here, but you should _never_ use `target_link_libraries` without a visibility specifier. It does _not_ default to one of them. Instead, it enables weird backwards-compatible behaviors that break in strange ways. Don't shoot yourself in the foot for no reason.

Comment: Well in trying to create a full example, I found it working. Then I cleaned my real solution and found that it is actually working...must have been some issue with making the changes on the existing solution.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue on Ninja. Here's my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
project(test)

add_executable(my_tool something.c)

add_library(my_helper helper.c)
add_dependencies(my_helper my_tool)

add_executable(my_test test.c)
target_link_libraries(my_test PRIVATE my_helper)
```

Then at the console I see this:

```
alex@alex-ubuntu:~/test$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.22.1

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
alex@alex-ubuntu:~/test$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 9.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build
alex@alex-ubuntu:~/test$ cmake --build build/ --target my_test -- -nv
[1/6] /usr/bin/cc    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/my_tool.dir/something.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/my_tool.dir/something.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/my_tool.dir/something.c.o -c /home/alex/test/something.c
[2/6] : && /usr/bin/cc   CMakeFiles/my_tool.dir/something.c.o -o my_tool   && :
[3/6] /usr/bin/cc    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/my_helper.dir/helper.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/my_helper.dir/helper.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/my_helper.dir/helper.c.o -c /home/alex/test/helper.c
[4/6] /usr/bin/cc    -MD -MT CMakeFiles/my_test.dir/test.c.o -MF CMakeFiles/my_test.dir/test.c.o.d -o CMakeFiles/my_test.dir/test.c.o -c /home/alex/test/test.c
[5/6] : && /usr/bin/cmake -E rm -f libmy_helper.a && /usr/bin/ar qc libmy_helper.a  CMakeFiles/my_helper.dir/helper.c.o && /usr/bin/ranlib libmy_helper.a && :
[6/6] : && /usr/bin/cc   CMakeFiles/my_test.dir/test.c.o -o my_test  libmy_helper.a && :
```

Clearly the tool is built even if I only ask for the test, at least on Ninja. I have no reason to believe this wouldn't work on Windows/VS, too (I do this all the time).

Please post a *complete, minimal, reproducible example* with all the commands and tool versions necessary to replicate it. Can't know if it's a bug without an MRE.